# Configure Gmail in Outlook for Office 365 MSO (Error: 0x800ccc92)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, office365, pop3

After setting up my email (POP) in Outlook, I have been receiving lots of pop-up notifications.

When I have decided to finally address this uncommon situation, I have noticed that there was an error behind: 0x800ccc92.

That is happening even with the "less secure apps" on ([Check if it is On/Off](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)).

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the problem, I have started by securing my email, and configuring the 2-Step Verification ([in the security section](https://myaccount.google.com/security)).

> Note: The "Less secure app access" becomes unavailable for accounts
>   with 2-Step Verification enabled.

After that, I generated an "[App password](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)" for Outlook (Mail on Windows Computer).

[image: Generate App password - 1]

Then I pressed the button "Generate" and got the following:

[image: App password - 2]

With that password, I just had to use it on the popup notification, with my email address.

PS. I have deleted the pw displayed in the image - it serves only as an illustration (avoid sharing it with others).